# phpmyadmin localhost error

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I have install Apache, PHP, MySQL on MAC 10.8.1 and then I have installed the phpmyadmin by issuing the command in terminal `- sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin`.

After this, in my web browser I type... localhost/phpmyadmin, it give the error message below.

> Not found
>
> The requested URL /phpmyadmin was not found on this server.
>   Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_ssl/2.2.22 Open SSL/0.9.8r
>   DAV/2 PHP/5.3.13 with Suhosin-Patch mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.7.2 Server
>   at localhost Port 80

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Apache on unix is usually case sensitive, try /phpMyAdmin. If that doesn't work is the phpMyAdmin folder actually inside your servers document root?

Answer (score 0):

For MAC OS, it does not recognize `localhost`, please use `127.0.0.1` instead.

In the browser,  you should use `http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin`.

Answer (score 0):

try to make an symbolic link between the directory of phpmyadmin and yours www

something like that :

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin/ /var/www/
```

and after that everything works :)

if you changed your path to an other directory just change /var/www by /home/your/path/to/www

Answer (score 0):

For those of you still facing with this problem:

- quickest fix: tell localhost which port to use.

Check which port is Apache using (in my case it was 90) and replace:

> http://localhost/phpmyadmin
>
> with
>
> http://localhost:90/phpmyadmin

Cheers!